# jqgrid navigation bar not rendering correctly

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

Some of my jqGrids have a strange behavior on the navigation bar.
On some of them I use the default Search and Refresh buttons and on there ones the navigation area floats left appearing right next to these buttons (not centered as it should).
The biggest problem happens when I add text to the search button "Search". This makes the button margins being wrongly calculated making the hober effect border shorter than the actual button width.

But like I said, this only happens in some cases and I can't figure out the difference between the ones working correctly and the ones that don't. This is not a browser issue as it happens the same in all browsers.

Heres's a screenshot (notice the search button with focus and the navigation controls position!):
[image: Problem Screenshot]
Have anyone faced this problem before?
This is my configuration os a grid that have this problem:

```
$('#ProductBrandListGrid').jqGrid({
        url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Controls/ProductsControls/Controllers/ProductBrandController.ashx?method=GridDataList") %>',
        datatype: 'json',
        mtype: 'GET',
        colNames: ['Name', 'Description', 'Actions'],
        colModel: [
    { name: 'Name', index: 'Name', width: 100, align: 'left', resizable: true, sortable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn']} },
    { name: 'Description', index: 'Description', align: 'left', resizable: true, sortable: true, searchoptions: { sopt: ['cn']} },
    { name: 'act', index: 'act', width: 25, sortable: false, search: false },
    ],
        pager: $('#ProductBrandListGridPager'),
        rowNum: 15,
        rowList: [10, 15, 20, 30, 50, 100],
        sortname: 'Name',
        sortorder: 'asc',
        viewrecords: true,
        imgpath: '',
        caption: '',
        width: 200,
        height: 400,
        gridComplete: function () {
            var ids = jQuery("#ProductBrandListGrid").jqGrid('getDataIDs');
            for (var i = 0; i < ids.length; i++) {
                var cl = ids[i];

                ce2 = "<input type='button' value='details' onclick='ProductBrandItemOpen(\"" + cl + "\")' />";

                $("#ProductBrandListGrid").setRowData(ids[i], { act: ce2 });
            }
        }
    });

    /* Add this line to show search boxes on the header */
    $('#ProductBrandListGrid').jqGrid('filterToolbar', { stringResult: true, searchOnEnter: false });

    /* Add this line to allow advanced search using the toolbar button */
    $("#ProductBrandListGrid").jqGrid('navGrid', "#ProductBrandListGridPager", { search: true, edit: false, add: false, del: false, searchtext:"Search" });
```

Thanks,
Alex

Comment: The button is probably with a fixed width. Right click it and "inspect element", and see if the css is fixed width

Comment: everything you have mentioned is a css [presentation] problem not much to do with your jqGrid

Comment: oh and why are you using `<input ... onclick="..."... />`? attribute? its bad practice, and you are defeating jquerys mission lool :)

Comment: @Ariel: I haven't specified any width for the button and I don't have any other css defined on that page other than the jqGrid's and JQueryUI Smoothness.

@Val(1): True, but I'm not setting any styles on it and even if you forget about the button problems why does the navigation controls are floating left?

@Val(2): My bad... I promise I'll change that to delegates :)

Comment: @AlexCode: From the picture which you posted one can see that the grid has width more as 200px. So you set somewhere the grid width. You problem will not full solved, but reduced if you would use larger value for the `width` parameter as 200 which you use currently.

Comment: @Oleg: That 200px width is just a formality as I'm using setGridWidth to resize the grid on window resize. I ended up removing all that logic from the grid toolbar so I don't cave this problem anymore, althogh it still happens...

Comment: @AlexCode: It is do important which **initial** width you use in the grid. The pager consist of 3 parts: the width of the left and the middle parts will be **calculated once** based on the initial grid width. Like you see on [the demo](http://www.ok-soft-gmbh.com/jqGrid/AlexCode0.htm) the pager position will be not changed after the usage of `setGridWidth`. Because of that I recommended you to use more higher value as the `width` parameter.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on what Oleg said about the grid's initial width I went to do some tests.

As I said, I have other grids that have custom buttons on the toolbar and don't behave like this but I couldn't find any differences that could cause this problem.

Inspecting my other implementations I saw that this only happens on the ones with a lower initial width. If I set the initial width to 500 it centers correctly and repositions itself correctly on setGridWidth.
I can even tell that the magic number is 415. Initial widths bellow 415px will cause this... anything equal or above 415px will make jqGrid act as expected. This leds me to think that this is some sort of hard-coded minimal width that is causing this bugging behavior.

Thanks for the help Oleg.
Alex

Answer (score 2):

I came across this issue today and noticed through 'Inspect Element' that for some reason, which I have to yet to figure out.  This even happens when the width is greater than 415, as well as grids without custom buttons on the bottom pager. So far, it seems to be quite random. When this issue occurs, the td tag with id = 'xxxpagername_left' has a specific width given to it.  On grids without this issue, 'xxxpagername_left' the width is not set. So, quick fix for the issue:

```
var pagerName = $($grid).jqGrid('getGridParam', 'pager');
$(pagerName + '_left').css('width', 'auto');
```

I have a ResizeGrid method that fires within the default loadComplete event for each grid; the code snippet hits after the grid is resized.

Unfortunately, I was not able to have the same success with setting the width to 500, or anything greater than 415.

Comment: I actually never solved the issue, I only hacked it. That project is gone already anyway but it's strange that the problem still exists after 3 years...

Comment: Yeah, it is odd, and not easy to replicate.  I figured I'd add another "solution" to this thread for the next person.

Comment: This is true for me too, is there any other solution, still experiencing this problem when width is set to null. I need width: null and shrinkToFit: false for resizing, changing width helps but I can't resize properly anymore, weird problem.

Comment: @AlexCode In your javascript the '_left' has a space in front which causes the script to not fire correctly, can you edit that please