# jqGrid: how to add horizontal toolbar

Tags: jqgrid

jqGrid is created in web page. If page width is decreased, rightmost columns are no more accessible.
How to add horizontal scrollbar to jqGrid so that if page width is small, jqGrid can scrolled 
horizontally to allow access to all columns ?

```
          grid.jqGrid({
            url: '<%= ResolveUrl("~/Grid/GetData?_entity=Strings")%>',
            datatype: "json",
            mtype: 'POST',
            scroll: 1,
            autoencode: true,

            height: 350,
            autowidth: true,
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try a similar approach but in this case you'll make use of the grid's scrollbars instead of the div overflow.

The idea is to resize the grid itself causing it to show scrollbars if its bouderies are smaller than its content. For this to work correctly the columns must have the option `fixed:true` otherwise they will resize themselfs to fit the grid's width.

Declare the DOM as follows:

```
<div id="grid1container" style="width: 100%;">
    <table id="grid1"></table>
    <div id="grid1pager"></div>
</div>
```

Then add the javascrip code to the page:

```
$(window).resize(function () { ResizeGrid1() });
function ResizeGrid1() {
    $('#grid1container').height($(window).height() - 55);

    $('#grid1').jqGrid()
        .setGridWidth($('#grid1container').width() - 2)
        .setGridHeight($('#grid1container').height());
}
```

Here I'm manipulating the grid's height too, if you don't want it just remove the setGridHeight line.

Comment: @AlexCode: Excellent solution. If texts are defined for navigation toolbar buttons in locale file or using 

`grid.navGrid("#pager", {
       edittext: "Change",
       addtext: "Append",
       deltext: "Delete",
       searchtext: "Search",
       refreshtext: "Refresh Whole Grid"
                     },.... `


ResizeGrid1 draws overlapping buttons. Button widths are too small. How to force proper buttons in navigation toolbar ?

Comment: I had that problem and found out that the problem was caused by the initial width of the grid, the one you put on the grid initial declaration.Somehow the grid completelly screws the width of the navbar buttons and also floats left the navigation controls.
Is this what's happening to you?
Try setting the initial width of the grid to 500 or higher.This doesnt make any sense, I know, just try it! :)

Comment: Here's my own thread for this problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6027307/jqgrid-navigation-bar-not-rendering-correctly

Comment: @AlexCode: I tested various initial width values. `width:500` does not remove overlapping. `width:10000` decreases overlapping more but overlapping still remains. larger width: values will **not decrease* overlapping more. There is plenty of empty space right to toolbar. How to remove overlapping ?

Comment: Can you post your code with some dummy data?
Or deploy it to an url that I can access?

Comment: @AlexCode: I can send you url if I know your email

Answer (score 0):

I've found this solution but its not perfec as in FF4 the window stops reporting width resize bellow 535px... couldn't figure out why.

My idea was to wrap the grid inside a DIV and set it to overflow: auto; width: 100%

```
<div id="grid1container" style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;">
    <table id="grid1"></table>
    <div id="grid1pager"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: jqGrid column width and total width is fixed. This causes vertical toolbar to be moved out of visible area in right side. How to enable scrolling using vertical scrollbar also if jqGrid width is greater than visible area ?

Comment: Using this, on horizontal scroll toolbar buttons or text becomes invisible, it is also scrolled out. I tried 
`<div style="width: 100%; overflow: auto;">

        <table id="grid">

        </table>
    </div>
    <div id="pager" style="width: 100%">
    </div>`
but navigation scrollbar is still scrolled out. How to make toolbar buttons always visible ?